# Efficient way to sort large vectors in-memory

Tags: c++, sorting, gcc

I need to sort large vectors of user defined data-type of 32 GB size in memory on 64GB RAM High Performance Computing (HPC) machine again and again according to some user defined function. I am using std::sort for the same. However, it is turning out that std::sort is taking a large amount of time >1 hour. Is there some other function which I may use which sorts faster than std::sort.

I am using the following gcc version on my system:
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4

Comment: Did you use your profiler to work out where the time's being spent? It could be e.g. operator<`, copy, move and/or swap are missing or inefficient, that you'd be better off sorting a vector of pointers to the objects, or that memory cache faults are the culprit - but if you don't do any actual investigation... what can we tell you? You might also look for a threaded/parallel sort, or code up your own (library recommendations are off topic here).  Showing your object's code would help us give meaningful advice.

Comment: @TonyD Can you suggest some freely available open source profiler for linux

Comment: you can try gprof http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/

Comment: @StegVerner: (also off topic), but yes - gprof, valgrind are popular choices.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use some mix of std::sort() (which uses quicksort algorithm) and mergesort and apply multithreading here.

For example, having some amount of cores in CPU, it might be reasoble to split the data, sort each part by std::sort on the cores simultaneously, and then merge them just as a mergesort merges sorted arrays.

Regards

Comment: `std::sort()` isn't REQUIRED to use any particular sorting algorithm. However, in GCC's case, it uses introsort.

Comment: @chbaker0 well, introsort is some kind of quicksort, isn't it? Anyway, that's not the point

Comment: @AndrewLavq Are you aware if some already existing library which does it for me

Comment: @StegVerner I'm not sure if there are such library, unfortunately. That's kind of a gerenal approach and it, perhaps, needs its own implementation

Comment: @AndrewLavq In case you have an example implementation..can you please share the same with me